# Updating one record triggers changes of all the records for one of the same primary key in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I used ADO.NET Entity Data Model for Entity Framework of a local DB in my VS project. There is only one table with two composite primary keys (UserId, Data) and one modifiable field (Status).

The problem is, when I try to retrieve one specific record and modify its "Status" field, all the "Status" for the same UserId change regardless their value of Data. (However the records under different UserId stay unaffected.) The updating codes are as follows:

```
public void updateStatus(string userId, string data, short status)
    using (var context = new MyDBContext()) {
        var data = context.UserDataStatus.Single(s => s.UserId == userId && s.Data == data);
        data.Status = status;
        context.UserImageStatus.Attach(data);
        context.Entry(data).Property(p => p.Status).IsModified = true;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I tried many different ways to update the record, such as using `.Where().FirstDefault()` to retrieve the record instead of `Single()`, or adding `.AsNoTracking()` after my `context.UserDataStatus`. However it didn't work either.

I found that sometimes entity framework doesn't handle correctly with duplicated / no primary keys, for example, I have to add `.AsNoTracking()` in the query as a workaround when retrieving data from the same DB. I wonder if it is the same reason that cause the updating problem, and how to solve it?

====

Updated:

Well, finally I've found the problem is caused by that the automatically generated EF Models gave only UserId as the primary key. Even though I chose "Update model from database" in .edmx, the primary key didn't updated at all. So I went to the .edmx model browser, manually update the property of "Data" field, and the problem was solved. And I don't have to use `.AsNoTracking()` in my query anymore, too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, finally I've found the problem is caused by that the automatically generated EF Models gave only UserId as the primary key. Even though I chose "Update model from database" in .edmx, the primary key didn't updated at all. So I went to the .edmx model browser, manually update the property of "Data" field (to set it as a primary key), and the problem was solved. And I don't have to use `.AsNoTracking()` in my query anymore, too.